# INSERT INTO statement in python putting quotes around my data?

Tags: python, sql, forms, variables, insert-into

I am inexperienced with Python.

So my code works to insert data into my SQL table, but I cannot figure out why it puts quotation marks around the names when they go into the table.

[What my table looks like in SQL after using my code to insert Matt Brown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJb1.jpg)

here is my code

```
FirstName = formData["firstName"].value
LastName = formData["lastName"].value 

print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
print()

# Some SQL to insert student
query ="INSERT INTO Students (LastName, FirstName) VALUES (%s, %s);"
print(query)
dbConnect.cur.execute(query, (LastName, FirstName))
dbConnect.conn.commit()
```

Comment: If they're strings, I'd expect them to have quotes around them.

Comment: Is there any way to make it not put quotes around them?

Comment: I doubt there's actual quotes around it. When you view it, it may show quotes around it to show that it's a string, but the string itself likely won't have had quotes added.

Comment: Which db do you use? Sqlite?

Comment: I'm using Amazon AWS

Comment: That's correct to put quotes. Why do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: `SELECT` this data from database and `print()` it on screen - do you see quotes ? And what program did you use to display results to screenshot ?

Comment: I was using mysql, and I want to get rid of the quotes because this is for a school project which is a Student/Grade manager, and the table showing the students names can't have quotes around them.

Comment: When in doubt if the quotes are really there, or if it's your client displaying it, run `SELECT LastName, LENGTH(LastName)` and see how many characters you get.

Comment: Use Notepad++.  It's really great for 'seeing' what the data really looks like!!